# "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" error only on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, nsviewcontroller

I know there are other posts with similar questions and I've checked them out but none of them seems to be about my specific issue, so please bear with me.

I'm developing an application which is supposed to run on iPad only, so no universal stuff: the MainWindow nib file is designed for iPad.

The thing is, as long as I run it on the iPad simulator from Xcode (both 5.0 and 5.1) everything works fine. But as soon as I try to run it on an actual iPad (with iOs 5.0) all I get is a blank screen and the "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" message on the console.

Here's some code that should be relevant:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

...
self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

VistaInizialeViewController *inizialeAppoggio = [[VistaInizialeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VistaInizialeViewController" bundle:nil];
self.vistaIniziale = inizialeAppoggio;
[inizialeAppoggio release];
 id debug = self.window.rootViewController;
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:self.vistaIniziale.view];
...
debug = self.window.rootViewController;
```

So what is confusing me is the following: if I run the above step by step on the simulator, the debug variable (the root view controller) is initialized and all, instead if I run it on a real device, it's just nil.

Ok, that's it from me, I'd really appreciate any help with this.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

1) The device is case sensitive, the simulator is not.

Are you sure that the nib file is called '`VistaInizialeViewController`', not something like '`vistaInizialeViewController`' or '`VistainizialeViewController`' ?

2) Check that self.splitViewcontroller is not `nil` - make sure that you have specified the correct `xib` filename for the main xib that's loaded on startup (or if you're generating it in code, out a breakpoint in and step through to prove it's being generated correctly)

Comment: Nope, the nib file is actually called "VistaInizialeViewController". This is from a copy-and-paste sequence, so I'm sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it.
What I did was adding the following code before setting     self.window.rootViewController

```
UISplitViewController *splitAppoggio = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
CategoriesViewController *categorieVC = [[[CategoriesViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
DetailViewController *dettaglioVC = [[[DetailViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
categorieVC.detailViewController = dettaglioVC;
UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:categorieVC];
NSArray *arrayVC = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navVC,dettaglioVC, nil];
splitAppoggio.viewControllers = arrayVC;
splitAppoggio.delegate = dettaglioVC;
self.splitViewController = splitAppoggio;
[splitAppoggio release];
```

With this it works correctly on an actual device too.
Why it didn't need this to run on the simulator, while this is needed to run on the iPad is still beyond me...